# All of a sudden unable to deploy the code in GitHub Actions

Tags: github, deployment, github-actions

Due to some reasons deleted the AWS s3 keys and replaced them. Unable to deploy the code in guthub actions due to the below errors.

"Resource is not in the state servicesStable"

In AWS events tab we are getting the below error.
"unable to consistently start tasks successfully".

If required let me know, I will share the task-def.json file.